# Why $|X_n|$ is a product of some i.i.d. random variables $U_1,...,U_n$?

Tags: probability

The question is as the following,

> 2.4.3 Let $X_0 = (1,0)$ and define $X_n\in\mathbf R^2$ inductively by declaring that $X_{n+1}$ is chosen at random from the ball of radius $|X_n|$ centered at the origin, i.e., $X_{n+1}/|X_n|$ is uniformly distributed on the ball of radius $1$ and independent of $X_1,\dotsc, X_n$. Prove that $n^{-1}\log |X_n|\to c$ a.s. and compute $c$.
>   [Image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3sZb.png)

I have the solution of this question but I could not understand from the beginning. Anyone can help explain how "by our assumption", $|X_n|=U_1\dotsb U_n$ where $U_1,...,U_n$ are i.i.d.? Thank you!

> 7.3. Our assumptions imply $|X_n| = U_1\dotsb U_n$ where the $U_i$ are i.i.d. with $P(U_i\leq r) = r^2$ for $0\leq r\leq 1$.
>   $$\frac{1}{n}\log |X_n| = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{m=1}^n \log U_m\to E\log U_m$$
>   by the strong law of large numbers. To compute the constant we note
>   $$E\log U_m = \int_0^1 2r \log r\,dr = (r^2\log r-r^2/2)|_0^1 = -1/2$$
>   [Image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eckpm.png)

Comment: Please type out the images so that others can find this post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set

$$ U_{n+1} = \frac {|X_{n+1}|} {|X_n|}, n = 0, 1, 2, \ldots$$

and $|X_n| = 1$, the result immediately follows from this assumption - when you multiply them together,
$$ |X_n| = \prod_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac {|X_{i+1}|} {|X_i|} \stackrel {d} {=} \prod_{j=1}^{n} U_j$$

Comment: nitpick: the distribution of $U_i$ is not $\mathrm{Uniform}(0,1)$; as the solution says, $P(U_i\leq r)=r^2$. Also I guess you want $|X_n|$ on the LHS of the second equation.

Comment: ok I go edit it. Thanks.